# How to check if a JSValue is a function

Tags: objective-c, javascriptcore

I am using JavaScriptCore to interact with Objective-C code

There is no isFunction method in JSValue, but I want to check if a JSValue is a JS Function and call it from Objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up inject a small javascript code to return the result of `typeof`

```
[context evaluateScript:@"function is(obj){ return typeof obj }"];
JSValue *is = [[context globalObject] valueForProperty:@"is"];
JSValue *type = [is callWithArguments:@[ is ]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no way to check that. You can only check that your function is an object (and in JS functions are objects).

According documentation, `-[JSValue callWithArguments:]` returns `nil` if the value cannot be treated as a JavaScript function. If a JS function doesn't explicitly return a value then it implicitly returns the JavaScript value `undefined`. So, looks like you can simply try to call JS function and handle the case if it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner that doesn't create any global objects:

```objectivec
// evaluates to true if value is a function, false otherwise
[[value.context evaluateScript:@"(obj) => typeof obj === 'function'"] callWithArguments:@[value]].toBool
```